# Open uncompressed TIFF files in OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, tiff

I'm trying to open two different TIFF files in python using OpenCV function imread

```
image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, file), -1)
```

The first file opens without any problem, but when I try to open the second file, imread returns 'None'. The only difference between the files, is that the second file is uncompressed.
Property page for both tiff images :
[image: Property page for both tiff images]

I also tried to open the second file using PIL and matplotlib with no success.

Has anyone successfully opened an uncompressed 16-bit TIFF image in python?

[Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fsoHjpfs9shOT3R78iMNgehN5iex7S2W/view?usp=sharing) an example file. Download it and open with InfranView if you would look to view the image (Google Drive does not support viewing)

Best regards,
Sondre

Comment: In case you don't get a solution, you can always use **ImageMagick** at the commandline to convert either way, e.g. `convert input.tif -compress lzw output.tif` or `convert input.tif -compress none output.tif`. If using V7 or newer, use `magick` in place of `convert`, i.e. `magick input.tif -compress lzw output.tif`.

Comment: Can you share the file `Frame_0_369.tif`?

Comment: I've updated the question with an example image. Not the same image, but the problem is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is not a valid TIFF file because it is missing the *"Photometric Interpretation"*, i.e. tag 262.

You can see the various tags with `tiffdump` which comes with **libtiff**

```
tiffdump Background.tif
```

**Output**

```
Background.tif:
Magic: 0x4949 <little-endian> Version: 0x2a <ClassicTIFF>
Directory 0: offset 2887048 (0x2c0d88) next 0 (0)
ImageWidth (256) SHORT (3) 1<1388>
ImageLength (257) SHORT (3) 1<1040>
BitsPerSample (258) SHORT (3) 1<16>
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
StripOffsets (273) LONG (4) 1040<8 2784 5560 8336 11112 13888 16664 19440 22216 24992 27768 30544 33320 36096 38872 41648 44424 47200 49976 52752 55528 58304 61080 63856 ...>
SamplesPerPixel (277) SHORT (3) 1<1>
RowsPerStrip (278) SHORT (3) 1<1>
StripByteCounts (279) LONG (4) 1040<2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 2776 ...>
PlanarConfig (284) SHORT (3) 1<1>
ResolutionUnit (296) SHORT (3) 1<1>
```

---

You can set the tag using `tiffset` utility that also comes with **libtiff**, for example:

```
tiffset -s 262 1 YourUnhappyImage.tif
```

Or, you can correct the application that produces it.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution to the problem, it is actually already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446804/python-read-and-write-tiff-16-bit-three-channel-colour-images/18461475). Using tifffile module opened the image successfully.