# Unable to read TIFF image using opencv-python

Tags: libtiff, imread, opencv, python

I am using the opencv with following config:

```
opencv-python == 3.4.3
python version --> 3.6
os --> Windows 10
```

I am trying to read a TIFF image using cv2.imread() function but am getting "None" as response. Below is the code I am trying with:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('abc.tif', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(img)
```

The result of this script is `None`.

I have verified that the given image is available at the required path. The same code works when I try to read a PNG file. I am guessing the problem is with TIFF format. Also, it used to work well with Python 2.7. I recently upgraded to Python 3.6 and since then am having this problem.

Comment: Can you share the image please?

Comment: What do you mean by read ? Display/show it ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am unable to upload the image here. It says the format is not supported. I am using a .tif image.

Comment: @Link By read, I mean, read the image as an array of pixels.

Comment: I feel this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446804/python-read-and-write-tiff-16-bit-three-channel-colour-images/18461475) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue in `opencv-python 3.4.3`.

According to the maintainer of `opencv-python`, it was an opencv issue, not an `opencv-python` issue https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/130. However, the issue seems to be resolved in `opencv-python 3.4.5`.

So the solution is to upgrade `opencv-python`.

Comment: I face the same tiff issue, even on opencv 4.2.0