# Save 32-bit floating point TIFF image

Tags: python, image, numpy, tiff

I'm trying to save a 32-bit floating point image (stored as a Numpy array) as a TIFF file using [tifffile.py](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/).

```py
import numpy as np
import tifffile

image = np.random.rand(500, 500, 3).astype(np.float32)
tifffile.imsave('image.tiff', image)
```

However, when viewing the output of the above code in Eye of Gnome, the image is entirely blank.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't know, but my first thought is that it might be setting the alpha channel to 0, since you're only providing 3 dimensions. Quickest test: try `np.random.rand(500, 500, 4)` instead.

Comment: @kwinkunks I gave that a go, but the same result.

Comment: How did you get on with a different viewer?

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that not all tools support multi-channel TIFFs with 32-bits per channel. For example, as far as I can tell Python's `PIL` library [does not](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes). But I think [`tifffile.py`](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) does, because if I use your code I get a TIFF that opens, and looks reasonable, in GIMP:

[image: GIMP with the image]

From what I read, Photoshop can read 32-bit TIFFs too. So I think the TIFF file contains your image, but whether it works for you or not depends on what you want to do with it next.

This question might be relevant too, although it's about using 16-bit *integers* not floats: [Python: Read and write TIFF 16 bit , three channel , colour images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446804/python-read-and-write-tiff-16-bit-three-channel-colour-images)