Not able to read 16 bit TIFF file using OpenCV
I am trying to read a 16 bit TIFF image and it is not able to read the file. When I print img it returns NONE.
import cv2
# from tifffile import imread

path = "day-02000.tif"

img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
print(img)

I tried using flags like imunchanged, anydepth, any color but still the same. Then I found the tifffile library which can read the file and when printing return the value. My primary goal is to read it with OpenCV.

Please share your TIFF - you can use Dropbox, Google Drive, Github...

Here is a similar question with different valid answers. Does any of them work with your image? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446804/python-read-and-write-tiff-16-bit-three-channel-colour-images

try cv.imreadmulti()

@MarkSetchell here's the link to the image [link] (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ALdj2ASy5WUGvo6S3hd6RsCy4emQ_xTs?usp=sharing)

@Markus tried using this im = cv2.imread('a.tif', -1) but still returning None

@ChristophRackwitz nope, getting None in return

The files contain 16-bit floating point, not 16-bit integer, images. Use another library that can handle float16 images, such as GDAL, tifffile, or imagecodecs.

note: at least one of the provided files contains the text strings {"shape": [640, 640, 3]} and tifffile.py (and tifffile.imread returns the array of np.float16 type) so if those files eventually disappear, that's probably a good way to reproduce such files for testing
